# Have Android Input Display NumberPad vs. QWERTY

Tags: android

In Android, how can I make the keypad that is displayed for user input, display a number keypad "123456789.+-", instead of the default QWERTY keyboard?  I need it to display this for ease of data entry.

---

```
          <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etCYLl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/myedittext"

                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                    android:digits="0123456789.+-"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/etAXEl"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: in my edittext when i click it and the softkeypad opens i need it to show numbers and + - sings and .    the + sign is disabled

Comment: umm...that's a statement, not a question. Pardon me if that comes across as glib. Please describe what happens when you run your program with the `<EditText>` that you gave. Then ask a *question*.

Comment: nice, im not having a problem whit the edittext but with the QWERTY keyboard i get a numpad with only visible button i can type are "123456789.-" but the plus sigh button (+) is not enabled how can i enable it plzzz :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a keyboard to use for the app.  You can change the custom keys used in the keyboard, check here: http://www.droid-life.com/2010/04/22/create-your-own-custom-htc_ime-keyboard/

Comment: android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                    android:digits="0123456789.+-"

Comment: this code gives me the result but only the plus sign isn't enabled   android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" android:digits="0123456789.+-" a good answer would help me enable it